# import multple phpmyadmin databses with one file

Tags: mysql, import

I created an export file for 30 databases i had then i deleted phpmyadmin.
Is there a simple way to import them?

I thought since there is the export feature there should also be the option to import databases, however it looks like you have to select what database to import to.

any idea's?

Comment: what is your backup file format.

Comment: @ZafarMalik both sql and sql.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly import from command line by below command-

Go to DB Server-

```
mysql -uroot -proot123 < /path/backup.sql
```

where root is username and root123 is password

Edit1:

```
mysql -uroot -proot123 any_db < /path/backup.sql
```

Comment: may be your backup file does not contain database create command then first you need to create all databases on server then use this command...most prob database create statement will be in your backup file as it is whole server (all db's) backup.

Comment: that does not work because i need to select a databse

Comment: "I need to select a database"??? if you have access on server then just execute given command. rest part will be done by this command.

Comment: when i execute the command i get and error telling me that i need to tell it what database to execute it in

Comment: then you need to create all db's on server and then execute my 2nd command with db, you can choose any db on your server.

Comment: I am assuming use database command will be in your backup normally dump backup keep this statement it will be better if you read your .sql file if use db statement is in your backup or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly import the sql or sql.gz file to import the databases.
Please make sure that your file must include the commands to create and use database. These commands are added during backup by phpmyadmin available options.

```
Go to import -> select file -> select format and click GO.
```

Comment: my file does not include the create database commands. since that is the case i assume its not possible?